# Debian configure OpenSIPS for Websocket and UDP

Tags: debian, udp, voip, sip

I'm trying to configure OpenSIPS with OverSIP so that I could make a SIP call between a webrowser and a sip client app like Yate or Linphone.
The call between two client apps (Yate/Linphone) works perfecly and between two browser clients (sipml5) also works perfectly.

But when I try to make a call from sipml5 to Yate/Linphone than it fails and when I call from Yate/Linphone to sipml5 than it rings but terminates the call when I allow the browser to use my audio/video devices or I try to answer the call.

I might be wrong but I think its a missconfiguration in opensips or oversip.

What can I do to make this work?